# Passport JS won't save new schema to DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to use passport.js with GoogleStrategy to authorize users for a web application I am building. I then want to store the users in MongoDB using mongoose.

```
// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, a token, tokenSecret, and Google profile), and
//   invoke a callback with a user object.
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/google/redirect'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(profile);
        console.log(profile.displayName);
        console.log(profile.id);
        new Models.User({
            username: profile.displayName,
            googleID: profile.id,
            memberOf: null
            //console.log('got this far');
        }).save(console.log('got to the save')).then((newUser) => {
            console.log(newUser+'was created');
        });
        console.log('came down here');
    })
)
```

That is my implementation of **passport** and **mongoose**. Once I get the profile from Google I am trying to store that user's displayName and googleID in my **User schema** which I want to save to my DB. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I run this program I see that **all** the console.log's output to the terminal `**except**` for the `console.log(newUser+'was created');` in the `.then()` I was hoping someone could help me fix this issue.

Comment: Hi there! You shouldn't be passing a console.log() to the `.save()` method. From the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save), you should either pass a callback function or nothing - in which case it returns a promise. Since you already have a `.then` attached to the `.save` method, can you try removing the console.log you passed into the `.save` method and see if anything changes?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, unfortunately, no, it does not seem to change when I remove the console.log. It still seems to be skipping the then() function and going straight to the last console.log

Comment: Was there an error log in the terminal(or wherever you're running the app)? Can you also try attaching a .catch() just after the .then() so we check if there is an error in the save process.

Comment: No there was no error log. I added ```.catch((error) => {console.log(error);})``` right after the then() AND right after the save() but it still seems to skip to the last log and no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Try adding an error handler in your `mongoose.connect()` method so you can see if your application is successfully connecting to your DB or not. That was the issue in my case.